# python : compare a text with file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, compare

I want to compare a shell command output with a text file using python, here is my code :

```py
   os.system('find / -perm -u=s -type f 2>/dev/null')
   suid_file = open("suid_list.txt", "r")
   os.system('find / -perm -u=s -type f 2>/dev/null > /tmp/test1.txt')

   lines = suid_file.read().split(',')
   lines2 = open('/tmp/test1.txt', 'r').read()
   for y in lines:
       if y in lines2:
         #matched
```

And the content of test1.txt is :

```
/usr/bin/su
/usr/bin/bwrap
/usr/bin/chsh
/usr/bin/ntfs-3g
/usr/bin/kismet_cap_ti_cc_2540
/usr/bin/mount
/usr/bin/vmware-user-suid-wrapper
/usr/bin/passwd
/usr/bin/fusermount3
/usr/bin/kismet_cap_linux_bluetooth
/usr/bin/kismet_cap_nxp_kw41z
/usr/bin/kismet_cap_nrf_mousejack
/usr/bin/newgrp
/usr/bin/gpasswd
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   lines2 = file_read.read()
```

second call of file_read.read() will return empty.
You should call outside the loop and store results in a variable which you can use inside the loop.

Comment: My suid_file.txt is like : root, ALL, gpasswd, /usr/bin/gpasswd

Comment: 1. What are the content of /tmp/test1.txt?
2. Can you edit your question with the correct code? (file_read.read() outside the loop)

Comment: See the message above

Comment: I precise that all lines in file '/tmp/test1.txt' are separated by break lines (stack error during paste I think) : it is the Linux shell suid binaries return.